# C++ SDL Reaction Time Game

Tags: c++, time, sdl

Me and my friend needs to create a reaction time game.
Something [like this](http://www.mathsisfun.com/games/reaction-time.html).

Right now we just managed to show an image of the red button, but we need help how to make a hitbox, where if you click the red button, it becomes green.

Would someone could show us how?

We are using SDL, I guess that's important to mention.

Here is our code so far:

```
#include <SDL/SDL.h>

void Plot(SDL_Surface *sur, int x, int y, SDL_Surface *dest)
{
    SDL_Rect rect = {x, y};
    SDL_BlitSurface(sur, NULL, dest, &rect);
}

SDL_Surface *LoadImage(const char *filename)
{
    SDL_Surface *sur = NULL;
    sur = SDL_LoadBMP(filename);

    if(sur == NULL)
    {
        printf("Img not found");
    }

    SDL_Surface *opsur = NULL;

    if(sur != NULL)
    {
        opsur = SDL_DisplayFormat(sur);
        SDL_SetColorKey(opsur, SDL_SRCCOLORKEY, 0xFFFFFF);
        if(opsur != NULL)
            SDL_FreeSurface(sur);
    }

    return opsur;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    SDL_Surface *screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(640, 480, 32, SDL_SWSURFACE);
    SDL_WM_SetCaption("Eksamensprojekt", NULL);
    SDL_Event Event;
    bool Running = true;

    SDL_Surface *sur = LoadImage("Red.bmp");

    while(Running)
    {
        while(SDL_PollEvent(&Event))
        {
            if(Event.type == SDL_QUIT)
                Running = false;
        }
        SDL_FillRect(screen, &screen->clip_rect, 0x000000);

        Plot(sur, 215, 140, screen);

        SDL_Flip(screen);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use SDL_Rect as a hit box. You can use SDL's own event handling system for checking when mouse button is clicked and the position of it. Then you just need to check if the mouse position is within the SDL_Rect.

You can read more about SDL [here.](http://www.lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/)
So... a little help on the way. You have a main loop and you pull events.

```cpp
if ( event.type == SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN ){

    //Get mouse coordinates
    int x = event.motion.x;
    int y = event.motion.y;

    //If the mouse is over the button
    if( checkSpriteCollision( x, y ) ){
        // Yay, you hit the button
        doThings();
    }
    else
    {
        // D'oh I missed
    }

}
```

Add this to the while, that will at least get you started.

Comment: We already looked at it and attempted, and still failed :(               If you, or anyone else could write it out for us it would be really great :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but we still can't get it to work.          There are 2 while functions, which one do I insert it into? And how do I make it display the green button when you click?                     I want it to change from red to green when you click it.

Comment: Put it in the inner loop ( under `If ( event.type == SDL_Quit )` )

To switch color you should do basically the same as you do in the plot function, only with a green surface instead of a red. You could use a bool value to determine which of the two surface you should blit.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
    while(Running)
    {
        while(SDL_PollEvent(&Event))
        {
            if(Event.type == SDL_QUIT)
                Running = false;

            if ( event.type == SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN ){

                //Get mouse coordinates
                int x = event.motion.x;
                int y = event.motion.y;

                //If the mouse is over the button
                if( checkSpriteCollision( x, y ) ){
                    // Yay, you hit the button
                    doThings();
                }
                else {
                    // D'oh I missed
                }

            }
        }
        SDL_FillRect(screen, &screen->clip_rect, 0x000000);

        Plot(sur, 215, 140, screen);

        SDL_Flip(screen);
    }

}
```

Comment: Please someone awesome at programming help us :D

Comment: Yes, now you have code for checking whether someone clicked the button ( assuming you implmented the `CheckSpriteCollision(x,y)` function. 

But you need to move the `Plot(...)` so that it blits the green surface when someone clicks the button and the red button otherwise.